# SKView in UIScrollView, SKNodes don't scroll

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, sprite-kit

So I'm trying to let the user two-finger scroll a `SKView` that they can paint on. I'm using a `PanGestureRecognizer` that is set with a minimum number of fingers as 2. I have the selector it calls shift the offset of the `UIScrollView` to which the `SKView` has been added. It scrolls the SKView perfectly... the problem is any SKNodes that have been added to that view don't scroll with it. Since a picture is worth a thousand words hopeful these will help(Thanks for any help you can give! I'm sure there is a simple solution. I just haven't found it ^^; ):

**Initial state**
[image: Initial State of screen]

**After Scrolling the view up**
[image: After Scrolling the view up]

**After Scrolling the view down**
[image: After Scrolling the view down]

**UPDATE:**
I added a contentOffset variable to the "GameScene" that, moved all SKNodes to a "root" node and then have this in the `update` run `root.position = self.contentOffset` and this does in fact get the nodes scrolling as well... however, if I start off with a screen that looks like this:

[image: Starter image]

If I then scroll up and down a bit and then add a new node by touching at the very top edge in the center then I get a screen that looks like this:

[image: After Image]

So as you can see when I scroll the nodes will "slide" a bit and this also shifts the way the touches are registered as well. Also, it doesn't seem to "slide" again after that.

It may help at this point to know that I add a physicsbody to each of the added SKNodes so that I can hit them with touches but set the dynamic = false so theoretically should only be moved if explicitly told to. So any ideas on this?

Comment: try applying the scroll offset to the scene's position as this will also offset all nodes in the scene

Comment: When I try to do that I get this message in my logs: SKScene: Setting the position of a SKScene has no effect.  And it has no affect.

Comment: ah, okay then assign offset to the node that contains the content - if no such node exists yet, add it and then add everything you used to add to the scene to the new node

Comment: I'll give it a go and let you know.

Comment: Ok... so that kinda worked... they move for the most part now, but seem to kinda slide and it also seems to move where the touches are registered on the SKView (touch center top and it puts the item about 50-60 pixels below that) any ideas? [May help to know that all nodes have physicsbodies so that you can touch them, but I've turned them all to dynamic = false]

Comment: Also they only seems to slide initially. SKNodes added after scrolling don't slide and nodes that have already slide don't slide either... it's really weird.